# How to invoke a listener or interceptor in @CacheEvict

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-cache

I have a requirement to invoke some functionality when @CacheEvict is being called. Is there a way to call a listener or interceptor to be invoked in Spring @CacheEvict?

Comment: If we go to the docs for the @CacheEvict:  Annotation indicating that a method (or all methods on a class) triggers a
 `org.springframework.cache.Cache.evict(Object)` cache evict operation. You can create Aspects to intercept this call, but it depends of cache framework what you use (for example GuavaCache, Ehcache or simply Spring)

Comment: I am using simple Spring cache. Could you please give me some pointer, how to create an Aspect for my below method  @CacheEvict(cacheNames="order", allEntries=true)
public void getOrders(){}

Comment: It is easy, you can find a loot of examples (https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/). In your case `"execution(* org.springframework.cache.ConcurrentMapCache.evict(..))"`, choose best point for you for example Before or After. I hope should work, without source code i cannot explain better.

Comment: update class package: ` "execution(* org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCache.evict(..))" `

Comment: Thanks a lot @borino.

Comment: the org.springframework.cache.Cache.evict(..)) at pointcut method is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, this is very "cache provider" specific since no 2 cache providers have the same capabilities.

For instance, I primarily work with In-Memory Data Grid (IMDG) technology like [Pivotal GemFire](https://pivotal.io/pivotal-gemfire) and the OSS version [Apache Geode](http://geode.apache.org/).  Both, of which, can be [used as a "caching provider"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#apis:spring-cache-abstraction) in [*Spring's Cache Abstraction*](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-plug).  With GemFire/Geode, you can register a [`o.a.g.cache.CacheListener`](http://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheListener.html) callback on the GemFire/Geode [`Region`](http://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/Region.html) (essentially a `java.util.Map`) that is [backing](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.0.2.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/cache/GemfireCache.java#L37-L39) the *Spring* [`Cache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) interface, and used in *Spring's* Caching infrastructure as the "Adapter" to the backing store.  As you can see with SD GemFire/Geode provider implementation, the ["eviction" triggers](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-geode/blob/2.0.2.RELEASE/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/cache/GemfireCache.java#L103-L105) a GemFire/Geode `Region.remove(key)`.  This eviction can subsequently be captures and handled in the `Region's` registered [CacheListener.afterDestroy(:EntryEvent)](http://geode.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/geode/cache/CacheListener.html#afterDestroy-org.apache.geode.cache.EntryEvent-) callback method.

However, this is just 1 way to handle notifications on evictions in your application.

Of course, as **@Borino** pointed out, you can leverage *Spring's* AOP support to "intercept" the cache eviction operation.  The advantage of this approach is that it is more generic and reusable across different caching providers.

Although, I would say that you should not be developing a AOP Pointcut expression based on the underlying "caching provider", as **@Borino** instructed, i.e. ...

`execution(* org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCache.evic‌​t(..))`

This expression ties your AOP Aspect to the `ConcurrentMapCache` "provider", the default in *Spring's Cache Abstraction* (and in *Spring Boot*).

What happens when you use Ehcache, Hazelcast, Redis, GemFire/Geode or multiple combinations of these "providers" in your application?

Rather, you can slightly adjust the AOP Pointcut expression to this...

`execution(* org.springframework.cache.Cache.evic‌​t(..))`

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html#evict-java.lang.Object-).  This is safe because all "caching providers" must supply 2 things: a [`CacheManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/CacheManager.html) implementation and a [`Cache`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) implementation for each cache specified in the application.  Again, the `Cache` interface is a "Adapter" to the backing store.  Again, [see the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#cache-plug) for more details.

There are tradeoffs with either approach.  Provider specific solutions generally give your more control capabilities, but using the AOP approach is more reusable. Do what is right for your UC.

Hope this helps.

Cheers!
-John

Comment: Thanks John. This is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

John's answer is on the right track, but it's important to know that the Cache class is not a Spring managed bean, the CacheManager is.

For this reason, you'd have to pull in additional AspectJ dependencies and do some sort of compile or post-compile weaving to target the Cache.evict method.

Answer (score 0):

i tried injecting cache manager to an aspect and set up my point cuts on methods that cache eviction was necessary like here:

```
package com.example.aspectdemo.aop;


import com.example.aspectdemo.domain.Customer;
import com.example.aspectdemo.service.CustomerService;
import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.*;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Aspect
public class CacheEvictHandler {

    public static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CacheEvictHandler.class);
    private final CacheManager cacheManager;
    private final CustomerService customerService;

    public CacheEvictHandler(CacheManager cacheManager, CustomerService customerService) {
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
        this.customerService = customerService;
    }

    @Pointcut(value = "execution(* com.example.aspectdemo.service.impl.CustomerServiceImpl.save(..))")
    public void loggingPointCut() {

    }

    @AfterReturning(value = "loggingPointCut()", returning = "customer")
    public void LoggAfterEviction(JoinPoint joinPoint, Customer customer) throws Throwable {
        cacheManager.getCache("customer-cache").clear();// remove cache
        logger.info("*** saved customer id : {}", customer.getId());// do what you like here, i added some logs
        logger.info("*** after eviction : {}", customerService.findAll());
        logger.info("*** cache evicted ***");
    }
}
```

here is where i save:

```
@Transactional
  @Override
  public Customer save(Customer customer) {
    log.debug("Request to save Customer : {}", customer);
    return customerRepository.save(customer);
  }
```